# return false when 3 conditions are not met

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to return false for a method when the user is not an admin or when the user_id is not equal to current_user id or if the user object is blank.
and want to know if this the best method to do it?

```
 def self.get_user_id(fname,lname) 
   user_id = User.where("fname=? AND  lname=?",fname,lname).pluck(:id)
   current_user = User.current.id
   return false if !@timesheet_admin? || (user_id != curent_user) || user_id.blank?
   user_id
 end
```

Comment: what are you getting?

Comment: what is the value of `!@timesheet_admin?`, `(user_id != curent_user)` and `user_id.blank?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got an issue in your code currently where you are returning an array of ids. You are also naming an id variable as though it were a record, which could be confusing. Let's try cleaning that up first.

**Step 1**

```
def self.get_user_id(fname,lname) 
  user_id = User.find_by(fname: fname, lname: lname).id
  current_user_id = User.current.id

  return false if !@timesheet_admin? || (user_id != current_user_id) || user_id.blank?

  user_id
end
```

Okay, now we can see the logic a bit more. You have a class instance variable here, which seems dangerous at worst, and difficult to understand at best. That may be part of your problem. Let's assume it isn't. Here's another way to show this logic that might be more readable.

**Step 2**

```
def self.invalid_id?(user_id, current_user_id)
  !@timesheet_admin? ||
    user_id != current_user_id ||
    user_id.blank?
end

def self.get_user_id(fname,lname) 
  user_id = User.find_by(fname: fname, lname: lname).id
  current_user_id = User.current.id

  invalid_id?(user_id, current_user_id) ? false : user_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to shorten it to return just the evaluated expression since it evaluates to a boolean

`return !@timesheet_admin? || (user_id != curent_user) || user_id.blank?`